# Iterate Through SQL Table Rows and Sum XML Nodes

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called students which has a column called All_Marks that is of type XML. Each entry is All_Marks is in this style

```
<Marks>
  <Math>20</Math>
  <Science>30</Science>
</Marks>
```

There is another column in students called Total_Marks. I would like to sum of the values in the XML of each student and insert that value into that student's respective Total_Marks column

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE s1
SET Total_Marks = (SELECT SUM(xc.value('(.)[1]', 'int')) 
                   FROM dbo.Students s2
                   CROSS APPLY All_Marks.nodes('/Marks/*') AS XT(XC)
                   WHERE s2.StudID = s1.StudID)
FROM dbo.Students s1
```

For each student in `dbo.Students`, it calculates the sum of the numerical values of the topics stored in the `All_Marks` XML inside the `<Marks>` element, and updates the column `Total_Marks` for that student with the sum of his/her marks.

Comment: what does the xc stand for? and where is StudID coming from?

Comment: @tjc: `XT` is the name of the "virtual" table of XML fragments created by the `.nodes()` function, and `XC` is the name of the column of that virtual table. `StudID` is just my assumption of a **primary key** of the `Students` table - you need to have *some* way of uniquely identifying each row ......